# Can't generate a nomenclature

Tags: texshop, nomenclature

I'm trying to make a document work with a nomenclature in TeXShop on Mac OSX. When running the below:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature 

\begin{document}

\section*{nomenclature}

\nomenclature{$J$}{Juice}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{Apples}%
\nomenclature{$O$}{Oranges}%
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2014] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file L_Baron_Final_Report.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in L_Baron_Final_Report.ind.
Transcript written in L_Baron_Final_Report.ilg.
```

And I see nothing where I want my nomenclature. 
In Library/TeXShop/Engines I have Nomenclature.engine which contains:

```
#!/bin/sh

bfname=$(dirname "$1")/"`basename "$1" .tex`"
makeindex "$bfname".nlo -s nomencl.ist -o "$bfname".nls
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Run the nomenclature thing i.e pick that as the engine. Your output shows that it is running on the `.idx` file to create an `.ind` but you seem to need it to run on the `.nlo` file and create an `.nls`. That's what that engine is for.

Comment: Thanks, how do I pick a different engine?

Comment: Er... It is several years since I used TeXShop. Is there a drop down menu which currently says something like *pdflatex*? Or is there a *typeset* sub-menu in the menus?

Comment: Look in the 'help' menu. The online version of the manual is from 2006 and still talking about the time before MacTeX.